# How to export an EXE native installer on Mac from an AIR project

Tags: apache-flex, air

I have an AIR application and I can export it to a DMG (native Mac application). However, I don't see how to export to an Windows EXE file.

**More details**
I'm using Mac OSX 10.8.2, Flash Builder 4.7, AIR 3.6 and Flex 4.6.

Comment: How can Mac exports an EXE, which does not even run in Mac OS system? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: AIR is a cross platform development platform. It can take the same code base and export to multiple targets including the browser, Android, iOS, Mac and Windows. I have options to export to these various platforms from the release build menu (except not seeing native Windows option).

Comment: i know what AIR is. You can't see DMG option when you export in Windows too ( Worth to mention, AIR is banned from iOS. ). Use Windows to export Windows executable.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Your information that AIR is banned from iOS is ~3 years out of date.  The Captive Runtime feature allows you to deploy AIR Built applications to iOS.  There are thousands of AIR applications in the iOS app store and many AIR games have been top sellers in the app store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create an exe on a Mac; you must do so in a Windows operating system.  That can be Windows running virtualized on the mac hardware, though.

Similarly, you can't create a DMG file on a Windows machine.

Comment: Could I create an AIR application on Mac that will install on Windows?

Comment: Yes, you can create an AIR app on a Mac that will install on Windows; but not using Captive Runtime. You'll have to create a .AIR file.